# Mysql request from two tables with counting

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables

```
**users**

id name
1  Name1
2  Name2

**tasks**

id user_id title
1  1       Task1 
2  1       Task2                                    
3  2       Task3
```

My request:

```
SELECT 
    U.*,
    COUNT(T.id) AS tasks_total 
FROM 
    `#__users` AS U
LEFT JOIN
    `#__tasks` AS T
ON
    U.id = T.user_id
```

I think something wrong here...

I wan't to get results:

```
id name  tasks_total
1  Name1 2
2  Name2 1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to group the result by id

```
SELECT 
    U.*,
    COUNT(T.id) AS tasks_total 
FROM 
    `#__users` AS U
LEFT JOIN
    `#__tasks` AS T
ON
    U.id = T.user_id
group by U.id
```

[demo on sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/898bb/1)

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing line functions and aggregate functions. One way around this is to have the aggregation done in a subquery:

```
SELECT 
    U.*,
    tasks_total 
FROM 
    `#__users` AS U
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT   user_id, COUNT(*) AS tasks_total 
     FROM     `#__tasks` 
     GROUP BY user_id) AS T
ON
    U.id = T.user_id
```